# Powershell Invoke-Command inDisconnected Session timeout?

Tags: python, powershell, timeout, config

I'm trying to run a python script from a remote machine using powershell. I'm using the -indisconnectedsession parameter but I think it's forcing a 2 hour timeout? When I run the python script from within the remote machine using the command line it doesn't time out. Can someone please clarify how I can delay the timeout for disconnected sessions.

My powershell command is as follows:

```
function Run-RemoteAsync($computerName, $pname, $scriptPath, $pargs)
{
    $cred = Get-QRemote-Credential
    Invoke-Command -indisconnectedsession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {powershell -c "$Using:pname '$Using:scriptPath' $Using:pargs"} -ConfigurationName QRemoteConfiguration
}
```

Comment: Why is the script taking more than two hours to run? This sounds like an XY problem, can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I figured it out. Apparently when you use indisconnected session, the default time is 2 hours so you need to specify a timeout parameter to extend it.